# ASP.NET MVC Scaffolding para qualquer tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffold

Alguém sabe uma forma de eu gerar `CRUD` automático para minhas tabelas do banco usando MVC?

Tenho 5 tabelas e gostaria de gerar `SinglePage apps` de forma automática para elas, sem precisar gerar várias `views/controllers`. A ideia é criar telas de administração básicas para gerenciar estas tabelas que são de controle interno meu e não preciso de designs trabalhados.

A ideia é se surgir outra tabela no futuro eu só precise selecionar em um combobox qual eu quero gerenciar e já seja listados os valores no grid com botões de `insert/update/delete`.

Já pesquisei algumas coisas mas o que encontro ainda exige um trabalho considerável para fazer o `Scaffolding` e cria vários arquivos `views/controller`.

Comment: Você quer gear as `Views` a partir da sua base de dados?

Comment: @rodrigorf Você está usando Code First?

Comment: @RenanCarlos Database First.

Comment: @JcSaint, exato, gerar as views/controllers, mas queria saber se existe uma forma de gerar uma view/controller genérica que atendesse várias tabelas. Se não for possível, pelo menos gerar tudo de forma automatica e já com os métodos CRUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, usando o [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4).

Só que tem um problema: essa ferramenta, além de ser um Beta, não foi atualizada para o Visual Studio 2015.

Assim sendo, [este cara atualizou a ferramenta pra gente](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/). [O link para ela está aqui](http://1drv.ms/1IkWSkR).

Depois de instalar o VSIX, você precisará voltar o .NET Framework para a versão 4.5.1, senão não funciona.

[image: Framework 4.5.1]

Feito isso, clique com o botão direito no seu projeto e selecione a opção **Entity Framework > Reverse Engineer Code First**.

[image: Reverse Engineer Code First]

Escolha o servidor e o nome do banco de dados que você deseja fazer o *Scaffolding*. A ferramenta irá replicar para o código todas as tabelas do banco de dados selecionado.

[image: Connection Properties]

Se tudo foi feito certo, a ferramenta fará o *Scaffolding* em segundo plano.

Duas observaçoes:

1. A ferramenta cria um diretório chamado `Mapping` com os mapeamentos das entidades em classes separadas. Não é incorreto usar dessa forma, mas deve ser desecorajado por ser uma abordagem antiga e prolixa, que dificulta a manutenção do projeto;
2. A ferramenta não faz *Scaffolding* de *Controllers* e *Views*: somente de *Models*. Para os demais ítens de *Scaffolding*, você terá que usar o [*Scaffolding* nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a2999%20scaffolding) ou o [MvcScaffolding](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a2999%20mvcscaffolding).

Comment: Agradeço o post bem completo Cigano, pelo que entendi pelo visto não vou encontrar uma ferramenta que gere esse controllers/views para mim de forma fácil, mas fiquei com a sensação que esse Power Tool gera apenas as Entidades sem CRUD, me corrija se estiver enganado, ainda vou testar :).  Outra coisa, você comentou sobre não ser uma boa prática usar esse modelo de mapping, saberia indicar um outro caminho?

Comment: Fazer tudo numa ferramenta só não existe, de fato. Muita informação dos mapeamentos não precisa ser usada porque o próprio *Model* já expressa o relacionamento. As demais informações podem ser substituídas por decoração de atributos. Neste caso, seria necessário você antes modificar o *Model* trazido do banco pra depois eliminar a classe de mapeamento.

Comment: Show. Já facilita minha vida de qualquer forma. Obrigado